# constexpr initializing with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, constexpr

I am trying to initialize a constexpr declaration with a pointer to int which is a const object. I also try to define an object with a object that is not a const type.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
constexpr int *np = nullptr; // np is a constant to int that points to null;
int j = 0;
constexpr int i = 42; // type of i is const int
constexpr const int *p = &i; // p is a constant pointer to the const int i;
constexpr int *p1 = &j; // p1 is a constant pointer to the int j; 
}
```

g++ log:

```
constexpr.cc:8:27: error: ‘& i’ is not a constant expression
constexpr.cc:9:22: error: ‘& j’ is not a constant expression
```

I believe it is because the objects in main have no fixed addresses, thus g++ is throwing error messages back at me; how would I correct this? Without using literal types.

Comment: Well, yeah. Variables only have addresses at runtime when they are assigned one.

Comment: @chris Yes. How would I define a function to have its objects to have a fixed address? Would I just declare the function as constexpr?

Comment: @chris Can you explain your point more? The whole point of constexpr is that is defined at compiletime with mainly literal types (they're expections). My point is objects within functions have temporary addresses assigned to them (for obvious reasons). Here g++ is throwing me the error messages due to those temp memory addresses. How could I declare a function that would not do this (ie, allow all objects to be fixed during control of flow).

Comment: I highly doubt you can associate addresses or pointers to variables with `constexpr` at all.

Comment: Note that literal types cannot be used here.

Comment: @JesseGood How else are you supposed to enforce compile time evaluation?

Comment: @TheBlueCat: My point was you cannot take the address of a temporary object. A literal evaluates to a temporary, so cannot be used. Unless I misunderstood what you mean by `Without using literal types`.

Comment: Unfortunately this example works fine in VS 2015. Poor Microsoft.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make them `static` to fix their addresses:

```
int main()
{
  constexpr int *np = nullptr; // np is a constant to int that points to null;
  static int j = 0;
  static constexpr int i = 42; // type of i is const int
  constexpr const int *p = &i; // p is a constant pointer to the const int i;
  constexpr int *p1 = &j; // p1 is a constant pointer to the int j; 
}
```

This is known as an *address constant expression* [5.19p3]:

> An address constant expression is a prvalue core constant expression
>   of pointer type that evaluates to the address of an object with static
>   storage duration, to the address of a function, or to a null pointer
>   value, or a prvalue core constant expression of type std::nullptr_t.

Comment: Isn't the address of a static variable defined at link-time, not at compile-time?

Comment: @anton_rh: Yes, the address is determined at link-time. That does not conflict with  my answer above though.

Comment: @JesseGood  I think it's a good point to elaborate on, though.  That a `constexpr` _can_ be a value resolved after compile time.

Comment: If you look at the implementation then you see what actually happens is that the compiler will generate a constant + a linker reference how to fix up the constant relative to the link address.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
// define i/j outside the function body, as mentioned in the book "c++ primer"
int j = 0;
constexpr int i = 42; // type of i is const int
int main()
{
   constexpr int *np = nullptr; // np is a constant to int that points to null;
   constexpr const int *p = &i; // p is a constant pointer to the const int i;
   constexpr int *p1 = &j; // p1 is a constant pointer to the int j; 
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).