# Is pointer type a literal type?

Tags: c++

A scalar type is defined as

> Trait class that identifies whether T is a scalar type. A scalar type
>   is a type that has built-in functionality for the addition operator
>   without overloads (arithmetic, pointer, member pointer, enum and
>   std::nullptr_t).
>
> It inherits from integral_constant as being either true_type or
>   false_type, depending on whether T is a scalar type, no matter its
>   const and/or volative qualification.

It means pointer is scalar type.

Now if we go to definition of literal type:

> A type is a literal type if it is:
>
> - a scalar type; or
> - a reference type; or
> - an array of literal type; or 
>     -a class type (Clause 9) that has all of the following properties:
>
>   - it has  a trivial destructor,
>   - every constructor call and full-expression in the brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members (if any) is a constant expression (5.19),
>   - it is an aggregate type (8.5.1) or  has at least one constexpr constructor or constructor template that is  not a copy or move constructor, and
>   - all of its non-static data members and base classes are of literal types.

Now, combining above 2 statements, it means pointer is literal type. However pointer can not be constexpr. can someone please clarify?

further see following code:

```
int a = 7;
constexpr int *pointer1 = &a;
int main ()
{
  int b = 4;
  constexpr int *pointer2 = &b;
}
```

pointer1 is fine but pointer 2 gives error. does that mean pointer to global is fine but to automatic variable is not? Does standard mention this anywhere ?

Comment: "However pointer can not be constexpr." -- Are you sure about that?

Comment: Have a look at [SO: constexpr initializing with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13502591/7478597). Without deeper knowledge, but the answer looks for me that pointers _can_ be `constexpr`.

Comment: Please don't change your question in such a way that existing answers are invalidated. As it stands, both answers just appear to repeat what you added into your question, even though they answered the question you originally asked.

Comment: sorry about that.. there was no way to add code as comment of an answer ..

Comment: Answer came when i was modifying question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pointers are literal types. They can be `constexpr` under certain conditions:

> #### [expr.const] 6
>
> ... [a pointer is `constexpr` if] it contains the address of an object with static storage duration, the address past the end of such an object (5.7), the address of a function, or a null pointer value.

(Where *"object with static storage duration"* means a global or static object, or a subobject of such object.)

[A demo:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16c742dd27c20f43)

```
int x;

int main()
{
    constexpr int *ptr = &x; // Compiles.

    // Doesn't compile: `error: '& foo' is not a constant expression`
    // int foo;
    // constexpr int *bar = &foo;
}
```

---

Apparently GCC (with `-pedantic-errors -std=c++11`/`14`/`17`) happily accepts out-of-range constexpr pointer arithmetic: `constexpr int *ptr = &x - 10;`, which seems like a bug to me.

Comment: I get what you mean, but it's not quite right. In `int x; constexpr int *p = &x + 1;`, `p` is not null and does not point to a global or static object.

Comment: @hvd Point taken. Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, that's better, with the regular caveat that undefined behaviour renders an expression non-constant, so `int x; constexpr int *p = &x + 2;` is not okay. For completeness, they can also point to functions, when you're dealing with pointer-to-function types.

Comment: maybe "the address past the end of such an object" applies to both ends. anyway, that's likely a quote from draft, which is "incomplet and incorrekt"

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I assume *"the address past the end of such an object"* means "exactly one byte past the actual end (not beginning)". And the quote was there at least since C++14 and wasn't changed much...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat then I don't get why they didn't says so, because the written idea after translation to many languages (even in head), including mine native, sounds exactly as I offered: end would mean either end, and "past" as indefinite distance :P

Answer (score 3):

Yes they are literals; yes they can be constexpr.  To demonstrate:

```
constexpr int* foo=0;

int x = 7;

constexpr int* ptr=&x;

int main(){}
```