# C++ pointer as uintptr_t at compile time?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

In C++ how can I get the integral representation of a pointer at compile time?

```
#include <bit>

constexpr int x = 5;
constexpr auto y = &x;

int main() {

    // The following does not work since it is forbidden for pointers!
    constexpr auto i = std::bit_cast<uintptr_t>(y);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any hack to achieve this in C++20?

Any hidden compiler intrinsic or `__builtin` function?

I'm targetting Clang, GCC and MSVC.

Comment: Possible duplicate. You have to refer to static usage, see: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499658/constexpr-initializing-with-pointers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [constexpr initializing with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499658/constexpr-initializing-with-pointers)

Comment: Because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) that address (`&x`) is usually not a compile time constant. Some [relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)) could happen at dynamic-loading time (in [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0)...) at least on Linux

Comment: I'm not trying to initialize a pointer at compile time, I'm trying to get its integral representation at compile time.

Comment: From run to run, due to ASLR and other things, your pointer can have different values. Knowing this, do you think it’s possible that there is a single known vale of the pointer that can be known at compile time?

Comment: I don't mind if the value is different every time the program runs, I really just want a constexpr integral value that can uniquely identify a pointer.

Comment: You are using `std::bit_cast` to get the __value__ (in bits) of `y` which can't have a value until runtime.  You can't get a compile time value of something that can only have a value a runtime.

Comment: @JoãoPires, no, what you want to achieve in general is contradictory. The value must be known at compile time. If external linkage is forced for the variable, its definition must be unique for all occurrences further more.

Comment: *I'm not trying to initialize a pointer at compile time,...* `constexpr auto y = &x;` is trying to initialize a pointer at compile time. *...I'm trying to get its integral representation at compile time* `y` has no integral representation at compile time, since it only has an integral representation at run time.  `constexpr` is not magic.