# Initialize constexpr with extern constant

Tags: c++

I would like to initialize a constexpr variable with another variable, made visible by extern:

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
int const a[] = {1};
int const d = 4;
```

**test.h**

```
extern int const a[];
extern int const d;
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"

int main(void) {
    constexpr const int * b = a;
    constexpr const int e = d;
}
```

(Only) The second line in main gives the following error:

`error: the value of 'd' is not usable in a constant expression` and

`test.h:3:18: note: 'd' was not initialized with a constant expression`

Could somebody help me to understand, why only one of the two examples fails?

Comment: Everything in a constexpr must be constexpr,  extern int is not constexpr; For constexpr pointers also have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499658/constexpr-initializing-with-pointers